# Algorithm with O(n log n) time and O(1) space complexity vs O(n) time and O(n) space complexity

Tags: algorithm, runtime, time-complexity, space-complexity

I am curious to know which algorithm is better :

- Algorithm with O(n log n) time and O(1) space complexity
- Algorithm with O(n) time and O(n) space complexity

Most of the algorithm which are solved in O(n long n) time and constant space can be solved in O(n) time by paying penalty in terms of space. Which algorithm is better ?
How do I decide between these two parameters ?

Example : Array Pair Sum

1. Can be solved in O(n logn) time by sorting
2. Can be solved using hash maps in O(n) time but with O(n) space

Comment: If you have the space and are pressed for time, use the faster one. If you're not in a rush, but haven't got any space to spare, use the one using less space. If you're pressed for both, benchmark and figure out which one looks better, i.e. come up with metrics that capture your needs and evaluate against them. If you don't care either way, flip a coin/ask someone to say "A" or "B"/let your cat decide (the last one is a bit flippant, but basically: if you don't care, the choice doesn't matter)

Comment: @G.Bach:: agreed, but "ask someone" != "ask SO". (Ask your cat is fine.)

Comment: @rici If the choice is irrelevant, then it is irrelevant who makes the choice.

Comment: Which is better (1, 2) or (2, 1)? Depends on the value of x and y to you.

Comment: `Most of the [algorithms requiring Θ(n log n)] time and constant space can be solved in O(n) time [and space]` - now that's a bold assertion. Any substantiation beyond examples?

Comment: @greybeard Can you please extend your claim? Say alg costs O(nlog(n)). Can you solve this in O(n) in all cases?

Comment: Between the two of us, at least one seems not entirely successful in communicating the intention of my comment: I think the claim "quoted" to be fallacious, and wanted to taunt Anil Kumar K K and the audience at large to substantiate it. (I missed the bounty - five days into a visit to my father. I might try to find a decent counter-example.)

Comment: I tried to flag this question as primarily opinion based, but the bounty protected it. *Sigh*. Must simply downvote and move on.

Comment: @greybeard: I don't know of any algorithm for sorting an array of arbitrary-length strings that's O(n) time and O(n) extra space, where n is the number of strings in the array. I'd say that any algorithm that requires sorting will serve as a good counter-example.

Comment: I think this is fairly depends on situation and more on your requirement. for example you can refer [this](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2014/08/how-to-find-all-pairs-in-array-of-integers-whose-sum-equal-given-number-java.html)

Comment: I extended this thread here http://stackoverflow.com/q/32081723/54964 for the numeric algorithms where n is much bigger than 240.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Without actually testing anything (a risky move!), I'm going to claim that the O(n log n)-time, O(1)-space algorithm is probably faster than the O(n)-time, O(n)-space algorithm, but is still probably not the optimal algorithm.

First, let's talk about this from a high-level perspective that ignores the particular details of the algorithms you're describing. One detail to keep in mind is that although O(n)-time algorithms are asymptotically faster than O(n log n)-time algorithms, they're only faster by a logarithmic factor. Keeping in mind that the number of atoms in the universe is about 10<sup>80</sup> (thanks, physics!), the base-2 log of the number of atoms in the universe is about 240. From a practical perspective, this means that you can think of that extra O(log n) factor as just a constant. Consequently, to determine whether an O(n log n) algorithm will be faster or slower than an O(n) algorithm on a particular input, you'd need to know more about what constants are hidden by the big-O notation. An algorithm that runs in time 600n will be slower than an algorithm that runs in time 2n log n for any n that fits in the universe, for example. Therefore, in terms of wall-clock performance, to evaluate which algorithm is faster, you'd probably need to do a bit of profiling on the algorithm to see which one is faster.

Then there's the effects of caching and locality of reference. Computer memory has a huge number of caches in it that are optimized for the case where reads and writes are located next to one another. The cost of a cache miss can be huge - hundreds or thousands of times slower than a hit - so you want to try to minimize this. If an algorithm uses O(n) memory, then as n gets larger, you need to start worrying about how closely-packed your memory accesses will be. If they're spread out, then the cost of the cache misses might start to add up pretty quickly, significantly driving up the coefficient hidden in the big-O notation of the time complexity. If they're more sequential, then you probably don't need to worry too much about this.

You also need to be careful about total memory available. If you have 8GB of RAM on your system and get an array with one billion 32-bit integers, then if you need O(n) auxiliary space with even a reasonable constant, you're not going to be able to fit your auxiliary memory into main memory and it will start getting paged out by the OS, really killing your runtime.

Finally, there's the issue of randomness. Algorithms based on hashing have *expected* fast runtimes, but if you get a bad hash function, there's a chance that the algorithm will slow down. Generating good random bits is hard, so most hash tables just go for "reasonably good" hash functions, risking worst-case inputs that will make the algorithm's performance degenerate.

So how do these concerns actually play out in practice? Well, let's look at the algorithms. The O(n)-time, O(n)-space algorithm works by building a hash table of all the elements in the array so that you can easily check whether a given element is present in the array, then scanning over the array and seeing whether there is a pair that sums up to the total. Let's think about how this algorithm works given the factors above.

- The memory usage is O(n) and, due to how hashing works, the accesses to the hash table are not likely to be sequential (an ideal hash table would have pretty much random access patterns). This means that you're going to have a lot of cache misses.
- The high memory usage means that for large inputs, you have to worry about memory getting paged in and out, exacerbating the above problem.
- As a result of the above two factors, the constant term hidden in the O(n) runtime is likely much higher than it looks.
- Hashing is not worst-case efficient, so there may be inputs that cause performance to significantly degrade.

Now, think about the O(n log n)-time, O(1) space algorithm, which works by doing an in-place array sort (say, heapsort), then walking inwards from the left and right and seeing if you can find a pair that sums to the target. The second step in this process has excellent locality of reference - virtually all array accesses are adjacent - and pretty much all of the cache misses you're going to get are going to be in the sorting step. This will increase the constant factor hidden in the big-O notation. However, the algorithm has no degenerate inputs and its low memory footprint probably means that the locality of reference will be better than the hash table approach. Therefore, if I had to guess, I'd put my money on this algorithm.

... Well, actually, I'd put my money on a third algorithm: an O(n log n)-time, O(log n)-space algorithm that's basically the above algorithm, but using introsort instead of heapsort. Introsort is an O(n log n)-time, O(log n)-space algorithm that uses randomized quicksort to mostly sort the array, switching to heapsort if the quicksort looks like it's about to degenerate, and doing a final insertion sort pass to clean everything up. Quicksort has amazing locality of reference - this is why it's so fast - and insertion sort is faster on small inputs, so this is an excellent compromise. Plus, O(log n) extra memory is basically nothing - remember, in practice, log n is at most 240. This algorithm has about the best locality of reference that you can get, giving a very low constant factor hidden by the O(n log n) term, so it would probably outperform the other algorithms in practice.

Of course, I've got to qualify that answer as well. The analysis I did above assumes that we're talking about pretty large inputs to the algorithm. If you're only ever looking at small inputs, then this whole analysis goes out the window because the effects I was taking into account won't start to show up. In that case, the best option would just be to profile the approaches and see what works best. From there, you might be able to build a "hybrid" approach where you use one algorithm for inputs in one size range and a different algorithm for inputs in a different size range. Chances are that this would give an approach that beats any single one of the approaches.

That said, to paraphrase Don Knuth, "beware of the above analysis - I have merely proved it correct, not actually tried it." The best option would be to profile everything and see how it works. The reason I didn't do this was to go through the analysis of what factors to keep an eye out for and to highlight the weakness of a pure big-O analysis comparing the two algorithms. I hope that the practice bears this out! If not, I'd love to see where I got it wrong. :-)

Comment: This was a very interesting read. +1 for placing the limit on log(n) at 240, I never thought of it that way :)

Comment: You say `If you have 8GB of RAM on your system and get an array with one billion 32-bit integers[.]` One billion is 1E9. I have thought that the limit is 2^32 instead which is more than 1E9. What is the limit of 64bit integers in the array of 8GB ram?

Comment: @Masi My thought was that one billion 32-bit integers is one billion times four bytes equals 4GB, roughly half of all the memory on the system. If you need the same amount of auxiliary space, there's no way to fit it into main memory without paging something out to disk. With 64-bit integers, one billion integers would use all 8GB.

Comment: The signed integer of PostgreSQL supports Mersenne Prime (2^31 -1) i.e. 2,147,483,647 i.e. standard SQL and the maximum upper bound of the signed integer. I think that is the limit in the memory so 250M (= MP/8) in the 64-bit system precisely; one billion is too much.

Comment: @Masi Oh, I see what you're saying. There's a difference between the largest permitted value for a 32-bit integer (just over two billion) and the amount of memory required to hold one billion objects, each of which is a 32-bit integer. I think we're talking about different things.

Comment: @templatetypedef Can you estimate what is the memory required to store MP amount of objects in memory? You can assume that the maximum of all objects is MP.

Comment: @Masi Sure! Just multiply the number of items by the size of each item. 32-bit integers take 4 bytes each, and the number you've given is basically 2^31. Therefore, you'd need 2^33 bytes, which is about 8GB. (That said, I think I'm missing something because I'm not sure how this relates back to the original question.)

Comment: "Just a constant" but not a small one. Constant factors matter in practice. Of course the constant factors hidden in the O notation themselves play just as big a role

Comment: @NiklasB. Oh, absolutely! The point I was trying to make here is that the O(log n) factor is small enough that it's essentially a constant, so you need to compare the algorithms against one another in a more nuanced way to try to see which constant factor is lower.

Comment: "the number of atoms in the universe" is not very big number, in practical algorithms we face many larger amounts

Comment: @AntonMalyshev For algorithms taking a sequence as input, I think it's a pretty reasonable bound. For numeric algorithms - especially in crypto - you're right that it's a pretty low number.

Answer (score 6):

From experience:

- If you absolutely can't afford the space, head the O(1) space route.
- When random access is unavoidable, head the O(n) space route. *(It's usually simpler and has a smaller time constant.)*
- When random access is slow (e.g. seek times), head the O(1) space route. *(You can usually figure out a way to be cache coherent.)*
- Otherwise, random access is fast -- head the O(n) space route. *(It's usually simpler with a smaller time constant.)*

Note that usually random access is "fast" if the problem fits within memory that's faster than the bottleneck storage. (e.g. if disks are the bottleneck, main memory is fast enough for random access --- if main memory is the bottleneck, CPU cache is fast enough for random access)

Answer (score 2):

Using your specific algorithm example *Array Pair Sum*, the hash version O(n) time with O(n) space will be faster.  Here's a little JavaScript benchmark you can play with http://jsfiddle.net/bbxb0bt4/1/

I used two different sorting algorithms, quick sort and radix sort in the benchmark. Radix sort in this instance (array of 32bit integers) is the ideal sorting algorithm and even it can barely compete with the single pass hash version.

If you want some generalized opinion, with regards to programming:

- using the O(N) time with O(N) space algorithm is preferred because the implementation will be simpler, which means it will be easier to maintain and debug.

---

```
function apsHash(arr, x) {
    var hash = new Set();
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(hash.has(x - arr[i])) {
            return [arr[i], x - arr[i]];
        }
        hash.add(arr[i]);
    }
    return [NaN, NaN];
}

function apsSortQS(arr, x) {
    arr = quickSortIP(arr);
    var l = 0;
    var r = arr.length - 1;
    while(l < r) {
        if(arr[l] + arr[r] === x) {
            return [arr[l], arr[r]];
        } else if(arr[l] + arr[r] < x) {
            l++;
        } else {
            r--;
        }
    }
    return [NaN, NaN];
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're rolling your own non-recursive quicksort rather than using a library sort routine?

Comment: @templatetypedef - the reason is, it's faster than the built in Array.prototype.sort  ~~ function(a,b) {return a-b;}, if you check the jsfiddle you'll see the quick sort and radix sort implementations. If you replae one of them with the built in sort you may get a long running script error.

Comment: I'm not sure why this got downvoted. Is there an error with the provided algorithms or with how the benchmark works?

Comment: Until you run into a case where N is so large that you can't fit everything in memory.

Comment: @JimMischel - My conclusion was "•using the O(N) time with O(N) space algorithm is preferred because the implementation will be simpler, which means it will be easier to maintain and debug". How would you solve the above Array Pair Sum problem if N was larger than you could store in memory *arrayPairSum( Stream data )*?

Comment: I would like to get an answer to Ricci's question in the last comment, too.

Answer (score 2):

That's not true that you can always substitute an O(n lg n) time O(1) space algorithm, with O(n) time O(n) space one. It really depends on the problem, and there are many different algorithms with different complexities for time and space, not just linear or linearithmic (e.g. n log n).

Note that O(1) space sometimes means (like in your example) that you need to modify the input array. So this actually means that you do need O(n) space, but you can somehow use the input array as your space (vs the case of really using only constant space). Changing the input array is not always possible or allowed.

As for choosing between the different algorithms with different time and space characteristics, it depends on your priorities. Often, the time is most important, so if you have enough memory, you would choose the fastest algorithm (remember that this memory is only used temporarily while the algorithm is running). If you really don't have the required space, then you would choose a slower algorithm which requires less space.

So, the general rule of thumb is to choose the fastest algorithm (not just by asymptotic complexity, but the actual real world fastest execution time for your regular work load) that it's possible to accomodate its space requirements.

Answer (score 2):

To compare two algorithms, firstly it should be quiet clear that for what we are comparing them.
If our priority is space, the algorithm with T(n)=O(n log n) & S(n)=O(1) is better.
In general case, second one with T(n)=O(n) & S(n)=O(n) is better as space could be compensated but time couldn't.

Answer (score 1):

One should keep three things in mind while selecting an algorithm approach.

1. Time in which the application will run smoothly in worst case scenario.
2. Space availability based on kind of environment the program will run in.
3. Re-usability of the functions created.

Given these three points, We may decide which approach will suit our application.

If I would be having a limited space and reasonable data supplied to it, then condition 2 will play prime role. Here, We may check the smoothness with `O(nlogn)` and try to optimize the code and give importance to condition 3.
(For example, Sorting algorithm utilized in Array Pair Sum can be reused at some other place in my code.)

If I would be having enough space, then improvising on time would be major concern. Here, instead re-usability, one would focus on writing time-efficient program.

Comment: Assume you have a real-time application where you have the output out with just a timelag \tau. For instance, doing `x == x + 1` is T(n) = O(n) and S(n) = O(n) with signal having for instance, ECG signal as the input, just small amount of data. I think T(n) = O(nlogn), S(n) = O(1) is worser with such an application than T(n) = O(n), S(n) = O(n).

Comment: @Masi: That's right, Given that the amount of data set is small enough which means space would not be a concern even in a worst case scenario. Here, we can focus on time-efficient programs which would be definitely T(n) = O(n) and S(n) = O(n).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your assumption is true.
Giving the fact that in real life, unlimited resources do not exist and that while implementing a solution you would do your best to implement the most reliable solution (a solution that does not break because you consumed all your allowed memory), I would be wise and go with :

`Algorithm with O(n log n) time and O(1) space complexity`

Even if you have a big amount of memory and that you are sure you would never exhaust your memory using solutions that consume a lot of memory could cause many issues (I/O read/write speed, backup data on case of failure) and I guess no one likes application that uses 2Go of memory at start ups and keeps growing over time as if there was a memory leak.

Comment: Excellent addition! I think this one (T(n) O(n log n), S(n) = O(1)) answers outstandingly how to manage situation with dynamic data and issues of I/O read/write, backups and failures. I think you can represent continuous output also with O(n log n) algorithm with timelag \tau. Etc representation of ECG signal. Right?

Answer (score 1):

i guess best is to write a test,
actual algorithm, amount of data (n),
and memory usage pattern will be important.

here a simple attempt to model it;
**random()** function calls and **mod** operations for time complexity,
random memory access (read/write) for space complexity.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

int test_count = 10;

int* test (long time_cost, long mem_cost){
  // memory allocation cost is also included
  int* mem = malloc(sizeof(int) * mem_cost);
  long i;
  for (i = 0; i < time_cost; i++){
    //random memory access, read and write operations.
    *(mem + (random() % mem_cost)) = *(mem + (random() % mem_cost));
  }
  return mem;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv){
  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr,"wrong argument count %d \nusage: complexity n", argc);
    return -1;
  }

  long n = atol(argv[1]);

  int *mem1, *mem2;
  clock_t start,stop;

  long long sum1 = 0;
  long long sum2 = 0;

  int i = 0;
  for (i; i < test_count; i++){
    start = clock();
    mem1 = test(n * log(n), 1);
    stop = clock();
    free(mem1);
    sum1 += (stop - start);

    start = clock();
    mem2 = test(n , n);
    stop = clock();
    free(mem2);
    sum2 += (stop - start);

  }

  fprintf(stdout, "%lld \t", sum1);
  fprintf(stdout, "%lld \n", sum2);

  return 0;
}
```

disabling optimizations;

```
gcc -o complexity -O0 -lm complexity.c
```

testing;

```
for ((i = 1000; i < 10000000; i *= 2)); do ./complexity $i; done | awk -e '{print $1 / $2}'
```

results i got;

> 7.96269
>   7.86233
>   8.54565
>   8.93554
>   9.63891
>   10.2098
>   10.596
>   10.9249
>   10.8096
>   10.9078
>   8.08227
>   6.63285
>   5.63355
>   5.45705

up to some point O(n) is doing better **in my machine**,
after some point, O(n*logn) getting better, (i didn't use swap).